# How do mathematicians think about arbitrary elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, soft-question

When mathematicians state:

- "let $x$ be an arbitrary integer"
- "let $x$ be any integer"
- "let $x$ be an integer"

what do they actually mean?

I asked a very similar question here:

[Question about how to interpret arbitrary elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954362/question-about-how-to-interpret-arbitrary-elements?noredirect=1#comment8154118_3954362)

however, here I am not asking whether my interpretation is correct, but instead how most mathematicians actually think about these statements.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think this needs to be a second question. You could just edit your previous question to clarify.

Comment: Do you program? How do you think about x in `reverse_string(x: string): string`?

Comment: I sometimes say "Suppose that $x$ is an integer" instead of "Let $x$ be an integer." It means the same thing. Ok, so we know that $x$ is an integer, and that's all we know about $x$. By the way, I almost never use the word "arbitrary".

Comment: It means that whatever we are about to say regarding $x$ will be something that applies to all integers (since we have no other assumptions).

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yes I program (alot actually). The way I would think about $x$ when writing a reverse_string function is that it is the identifier to the memory location of my user's input (in this case, a string).